# Getting a unique pointer to an array from a std::vector

Tags: arrays, pointers, c++11, vector

I am trying to work with two libraries that have rather different ideas about collections. I'm getting data from one that returns a const vector&:

```
const std::vector<uint8_t>& Lib1::getData();
```

The other takes the same data as a ctor parameter, but in a slightly different form, and it takes ownership of the data before passing it along to a base class:

```
class Lib2 : public Lib2Base
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t []> buffer;
public:
    Lib2(std::unique_ptr<uint8_t []> & p_buffer; size_t p_length) :
        buffer(move(p_buffer)), Lib2Base(p_buffer.get(), p_length)
    {}  
}
```

I need a shared pointer to a Lib2 constructed with the data from Lib1. I understand that under the covers vectors are contiguous, like arrays, so I'm attempting to handle the conversion with [vector::data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), like this:

```
vector<uint8_t> buffer(lib1->getData());
auto bufferPtr = make_unique<uint8_t *>(buffer.data());
shared_ptr<Lib2> output = make_shared<Lib2>(&bufferPtr, buffer.size());
```

At this point, I expect bufferPtr to be a unique pointer to a pointer to the start of the array. However the last line there results in an error:

```
C2664: 'Lib2(const Lib2 &)' cannot convert argument 1 
from 'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t *, std::default_delete<_Ty>>' 
to   'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t [], std::default_delete<_Ty>> &'
```

(Alignment added for readability). I feel like I might have an extra level of indirection going on here, but after looking at this for too long I can't see where.

Comment: Please tell the author of `Lib2` that the proper way to accept ownership of a `unique_ptr` is to take the parameter by *value*, and that `p_buffer.get()` returns `nullptr` after `p_buffer` has been moved from: `Lib2(std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> p_buffer, size_t p_length) : buffer(move(p_buffer)), Lib2Base(buffer.get(), p_length) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_unique<uint8_t *>` is the a pointer to a *single* `uint8_t`, which has a different deleter than that of a dynamic array of `uint8_t` (`delete` vs `delete[]`)

To make that error go away, you'd simply replace the `make_unique<uint8_t *>` with an `make_unique<uint8_t[]>`.  Unfortunately, that merely solves the compiler error.  There's still a conceptual error.

Namely, "it takes ownership of the data".  Of the data that the vector already has ownership of.  You're trying to share ownership, and telling them both they're the unique owner.  When the first one is destroyed, the other is going to crash, because that's undefined behavior.  If `Lib2` really requires a `unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` (which is *very* strange, there's really no reason for `unique_ptr<T[]>` to exist other than C compatability...), then your only option is to actually allocate a new `T[]` in memory, copy the data to that memory from the vector, and give a `unique_ptr` pointing to that memory to `Lib2`.  Sorry.

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T[]> make_unique_array_from_vec(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> ptr(new T[vec.size()]);
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ptr.get());
    return ptr;
}
```